# How to put an icon next to text fileld in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to put an icon next to text field in jquery mobile.

```html
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="card">Verification Number</label>
  <input data-mini="true" type="text" name="card" id="card">
  <a href="card.png">
    <img src="questionicon.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have unclosed tags in your html code.

you have to close all the tags for the code working without errors.

> the img and input tag are not close.

Here is a working [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W8Asx/5/) for your needs

Have change a little bit your html code:

```html
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="myfield">
  <label for="card">Verification Number</label>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="text" name="card" id="card"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="image.jpg" width="20px" height="20px" id="myimage"/>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What you mean be saying "unclosed tags"?

Comment: i mean you have to close the tags like you with the div tags. for example: <div> </div> <---close ///  <img src="path/name.jpg"></img> or <img src="path/name.jpg" />

Comment: which libraries you use ? only this?

Comment: Jquery Mobile V.1.3.2

Comment: have update my answer.. take a look to the new fiddle and let me know something.